# Broken cygwin's git command

Tags: git, cygwin

Seems that my git under Cygwin is broken, following commands `/usr/bin/git.exe --version` or `/usr/bin/git.exe` does not do anything. If I issue `git.exe` in particular directory from Windows terminal I get following message: `The procedure entry point __cxa_atexit could not be located in the dynamic link library cygwin1.dll` I've installed following packages using `apt-cyg` command:

```
git
git-completion
git-cvs
git-debuginfo
git-email
git-gui
git-oodiff
git-review
git-svn
gitk
gitweb
```

Seems that binary is installed:

```
$ which git.exe
/usr/bin/git.exe

$ ls -l /usr/bin/git.exe
-rwxr-xr-x+ 112 wakatana Domain Users 1636893 Jan 10  2015 /usr/bin/git.exe

$ md5sum.exe /usr/bin/git.exe
85f986f8c9ee8d9573fd9b1a05af4260 */usr/bin/git.exe
```

I've not installed any other binaries or 3rd party tools for git except those mentioned above. What is wrong?

PS: I'm running this as non administrator user (I cannot use admin account).

Comment: What happens if you just try to invoke `/usr/bin/git.exe` directly, no arguments? Alternatively, what happens if you try to invoke it from a Windows shell? Also, for what it's worth, I've found using Git-for-Windows (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.5.2.windows.2) better than Cygwin.

Comment: @CBHacking thank you for reply, I've updated OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you're getting, the version of `git` in `apt-cyg` is linked against a different (probably newer) version of Cygwin. The error message you get indicates that the `cygwin1` DLL (which is the central component of Cygwin, providing all the Unix APIs) is missing a function, probably because that function was added to the library after the version that you have was compiled.

You can check the functions that a program or DLL requires from (other) DLLs (known as *imports*) and that a DLL provides for other code to call (known as *exports*) in various ways, but one of the best is [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/), a free utility that runs on any version of Windows and is useful enough that Microsoft has included it in prior versions of their build tools.

The solution is probably just to **update your Cygwin installation**. It looks like the relevant export was added in **Cygwin 1.7.32-1**, released in August 2014. See this post: http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/ANNOUNCEMENT-Updated-Cygwin-1-7-32-1-td110464.html. Of course, you should use the newest release version available.